# JQUERY adding image attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following jquery code which i want to add the styling to the image uploaded. Does any know how i can add style after the src in the jquery.

[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ppd2ex7m/3/)

```
 <div id="container">
  <input id="fileUpload" type="file" />
  <br />
  <div id="image-container"> </div>
</div>
$("#fileUpload").on('change', function() {

  if (typeof(FileReader) == "undefined") {
    alert("Your browser doesn't support HTML5, Please upgrade your browser");
  } else {

    var container = $("#image-container");

    //remove all previous selected files
    container.empty();

    //create instance of FileReader
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $("<img />", {
      // I want to add the syle here
        "src": e.target.result
      }).appendTo(container);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> // I want to add the syle here

You can simply add the style like:

```
"style": "width:100px;height:100px",
```

```js
$("#fileUpload").on('change', function() {

    if (typeof(FileReader) == "undefined") {
        alert("Your browser doesn't support HTML5, Please upgrade your browser");
    } else {

        var container = $("#image-container");

        //remove all previous selected files
        container.empty();

        //create instance of FileReader
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $("<img />", {
                "style": "width:100px;height:100px",
                "src": e.target.result
            }).appendTo(container);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="container">
    <input id="fileUpload" type="file" />
    <br />
    <div id="image-container"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it.

```
let imageStyle = "width:150px";
$("#image-container").append("<img id='theImg' src='" + e.target.result +"' style='"+ imageStyle +"'/>");
```

This can also be done as

```
var img = $('<img>');
img.attr('src', e.target.result);
img.attr('style', imageStyle);
img.appendTo('#image-container');
```